# How to create formula to use in the Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to create a formula so that I can apply that on the whole sheet.

I have tried this, but it's not working.

```
UPDATE Config 
   SET FieldLabel = 'F2' 
 WHERE CurrencyCode = 'A2'  
   AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK 
                       FROM Country 
                      WHERE CountryCode = 'B2')
```

So basically I want to generate the query

```
`UPDATE Config 
    SET FieldLabel = 'Beneficiary Account Name' 
  WHERE CurrencyCode = 'AED' 
    AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK 
                        FROM Country 
                       WHERE CountryCode = 'AE')`
```

and generate the query based on columns values.

[image]

I am just a beginner to Excel, so please forgive me for the easy question.

Comment: Formulas, in Excel, start with a `=`, the above is just a literal string. I would suggest starting with reading the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-simple-formula-in-excel-11a5f0e5-38a3-4115-85bc-f4a465f64a8a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the & concatenate values in cells as follows for example

Type the following in cell D2(use F2 and copy-paste) after putting in the values for A2,B2 and C2 as shown up in the image.

```
="UPDATE Config 
    SET FieldLabel = '"&C2 &"'
  WHERE CurrencyCode = '"&B2&"' 
    AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK 
                        FROM Mas_Country 
                       WHERE CountryCode = '"&A2&"')"
```

[image]

Comment: It's working fine, only one issue, when I copy the query, it's coming with double quotes, I don't want the double-quotes. I want this `UPDATE Config      SET FieldLabel = 'United Arab Emirates'   WHERE CurrencyCode = 'AE'      AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK                          FROM Mas_Country                         WHERE CountryCode = 'AED')`

Comment: @viveknuna It appears in double quotes because it has more than 1 line - the quotes tell it "this is all one block of text", rather than being 5 different items

Comment: You can see in my image in cell D2(not fully though) that i have got it exactly as you describe. You need a double quotes to indicate to excel that its a formula. Go to cell D2--> clear any existing data in it -> Press F2 and copy-paste exactly what i have shared

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with CONCATENATE Excel's function with some static values like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("UPDATE Config SET FieldLabel = '";F2;"' WHERE CurrencyCode = '";A2;"AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK FROM Mas_Country WHERE CountryCode = '";B2;"')")
```

After data generation just remembers to copy results and paste values of cells (not excel's formulas).

Comment: @viveknuna Depending on what Language your Excel is set to, you may need to change the Semicolons to Commas (`=CONCATENATE("UPDATE Config SET FieldLabel = '",F2,"' WHERE CurrencyCode = '",A2,"AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK FROM Mas_Country WHERE CountryCode = '",B2,"')")`)

Comment: @Chronocidal Thank you its working as expcted. you missed one thing, I have modiefied  `=CONCATENATE("UPDATE Config SET FieldLabel = '",F2,"' WHERE CurrencyCode = '",A2,"' AND CountryFK IN (SELECT CountryPK FROM Mas_Country WHERE CountryCode = '",B2,"')")`

Comment: @tdc please change your answer as per the Chronocidal comment